# Security in symfony. Looking for Bundle/tutorials

Tags: symfony

I am writing an app with symfony 2.

I have 3 areas on my website:

1. /admin - only for administration, I'v made separate bundle for Admin
2. / - for all users, they can see most of website and do most of actions
3. /user - access to user profile, and user data + '/'.

Is there any good bundle for this purpose? Might be also good tutorial?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Combining [sonataAdminBundle](https://github.com/sonata-project/SonataAdminBundle) with [fosUserBundle](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle) is best for administration. They also have good documentation.

Answer (score 1):

You can also look for these links:

- http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html
- http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/SensioFrameworkExtraBundle/index.html

I prefer use annotation for securing Controllers. For this case there is [`JMSSecurityExtraBundle`](http://jmsyst.com/bundles/JMSSecurityExtraBundle/1.0).

Basic steps:

1. Create firewall with different options for different places.
2. Secury manually actions if the url is custom (via annotations e.g.)

Also you don't need to create standalone Admin bundle. If you want separate admin actions from non-admin you can simply create several controllers with different URL prefixes:

- `AdminController (@Route("/admin"))`,
- `UserController (@Route("/user"))`,
- `DefaultController (@Route("/"))`.